# Extending react component and an additional class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to go the simplest way using Object.assign:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'

class MySuperClass {
  firstMethod() {
     console.log("method 1")
  }
}

const a = Object.assign({}, Component, MySuperClass)

  class CategoriesScreen extends a {

    render() {
      return (
        <View>

        </View>
    );
    }
  };
```

Yet I'm receiving the error :

```
TypeError: SUper expression must either be null or a function
```

I researched it but it fits to different cases than this one

How can I extend one object that includes both the MySuperClass and the react Component?

(PLEASE NOTE: I know I can extend Component in MySuperClass as a work around, but I'm interested to know how to achieve it with this approach, thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Object.assign(MySuperClass.prototype, Component.prototype);
```

here is a more complete example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-with-objectassign-c9es0

Comment: Thanks but I specifically wrote that I'm aware of this solution already

Comment: got you. can you check this snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-with-objectassign-c9es0